# SPOJ, ADDREV. (Most Solved #2) with python

Tags: python, python-2.7

Problem Statement can be found here: http://www.spoj.com/problems/ADDREV/

I wrote this solution:

```
N=input('no. of test cases bruh:')
yeah=0
while 0< N <= 10000 and yeah<N:
    a, b=raw_input(':').split()
    if int(a)<=0:
        yeah=yeah+1
        continue
    z=0
    n=1
    while int(a)%10==0:
        a=int(a)/10
        a=str(a)
    y=len(a)
    while n<=y:
        z=(10**(y-n))*int((a[y-n])) + z
        n=n+1
    if int(b)<=0:
        yeah=yeah+1
        continue
    z2=0
    n2=1
    while int(b)%10==0:
        b=int(b)/10
        b=str(b)
    x=len(b)
    while n2<=x:
        z2=(10**(x-n2))*int((b[x-n2])) + z2
        n2=n2+1
    fakeans=str(z+z2)
    ans=0
    n3=1
    while int(fakeans)%10==0:
        fakeans=int(fakeans)/10
        fakeans=str(fakeans)
    x=len(fakeans)
    while n3<=x:
        ans=(10**(x-n3))*int((fakeans[x-n3])) + ans
        n3=n3+1
    print ans
    yeah=yeah+1
```

The following bit of code is supposed to check and omit the zeroes:

```
while int(a)%10==0:
            a=int(a)/10
            a=str(a)
```

This bit is supposed to reverse the numbers:

```
while n<=y:
            z=(10**(y-n))*int((a[y-n])) + z
            n=n+1
```

I have merely used this repetitively in the program to get the answer.

SPOJ keeps on giving wrong answer. I have no idea why. It gives the correct answer every time, I've tried to write the program exactly how it has been asked but evidently, something is wrong even though i get the correct answer every time. I've tried to put in negative values, zeroes and i have tried to debug by inserting print statements as well. Everything runs as it should to me. What am I missing here?

P.S. I can't write concise code as i'm just a beginner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
N=input('no. of test cases bruh:')
```

I think the problem is with the input statements. Most of the competitive programming sites, check the output stream for the same format specified. In your case, its output would be

```
no. of test cases bruh:
:
34
:
1998
:
1
```

and thus the wrong answer, as it does not match the expected output.
Remove the help text from the input statements to fix this.

Comment: Exactly, please look at the output for your code for the sample input: http://ideone.com/stGNfq. It should be exactly the same as sample output.

Comment: See, that's the point `no of test cases bruh` and `:` should not be printed. Your code should only print out the output produced by the program in the specified format and nothing else.